# Redis Sentinel Connection using C# Stackexchange library

Tags: .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am working on a POC for which I have created 3 redis server(1 master 2 slave) and corresponding 3 sentinels successfully on my local machine.
When I am connecting to the sentinels it is not throwing any exception but during setting the key using  Stackexchange(C# redis client) 
I am getting the below exception:
"Additional information: This operation has been disabled in the command-map and cannot be used: SET"

But if I am connecting sentinels using ServiceStack Library for dotnet it is connecting successfully.Setting the key and retrieving also works fine.

**Can I connect redis senytinels using Stackexchange library? 
If yes kindly also provide the working example(source code) for that.**